# ? A graph is four colorable if and only if it is planar.

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory, graph-colorings

? A graph is four colorable if and only if it is planar.

Is this true, I know that if a graph is planar it is four colorable, but is it true that if a graph is four colorable it must be a planar graph.

(EDIT) The following would have been a better way for me to have ask the question.
What are the requirements for a graph to be planar?
What are the requirements for a graph to be 4 colorable?
Is there a simplification of the intersection of not planar and four colorable?

Comment: No. The "utility graph" on the far left is not planar but is four colorable (in fact, two colorable): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UtilityGraph.html 

Comment: Even easier to see: From Euler's formula, a planar graph has to have a vertex of degree 5 or less. (6 or less if it's infinite.) Draw two sets of seven dots each, and connect all the dots in one set to all the dots in the other. This is 2-colorable but clearly can't be planar.

Comment: In fact, you can use the Euler characteristic to bound the average degree of a graph drawn on any surface, so an analogous construction shows that for any surface, there are 2-colorable graphs that can't be drawn on it.

Comment: Not sure way this was down voted. I guess I was really looking for the answer Henry Wilton gave. I suppose I should have more directly ask the question but I was not sure the best way to phrase the question. Not to be a whinner but as this was the first time I visited the site a nice comment letting me know why this was not a good question would have been nice.

Comment: @unknown: I think people are downvoting your question because they feel like you didn't think about it enough before posting it. It's a fine question, but basically the very first example of a non-planar graph answers it.

Comment: Perhaps another helpful comment: the first subdivision of *any graph* is two-colourable.  So any topologically-defined class of graphs contains two-colourable examples.

Comment: I think the downvoting is rather harsh.  The question is of interest to mathematicians and is clearly written (albeit with some misplaced punctuation).  OK, so you know the answer to the question right off the top of your head?  Good for you -- that's much of the point of MO.  A substantial portion of the questions on this site are as obvious to _someone_ as this is to you.  Let's try to take smaller bites out of the novices...

Comment: Two 4-colorings of a nonplanar infinite graph are at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11453/which-lattices-have-more-than-one-minimal-periodic-coloring

Comment: @Pete: I'm not so sure in this case. It's very well-known that graphs are planar iff it does not have K_5 or K_3,3 as a minor, and moreover if you google "planar graph", the first hit is the wikipedia page, which contains this statement. Then it is very easy to see that K_3,3 is 2-colorable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A graph is planar if and only if it does not have $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.   As Hunter's comment points out, $K_{3,3}$ is bipartite, ie two-colourable.