# Which lattices have more than one minimal periodic coloring?

Tags: graph-colorings, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lattices

The lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$ has an essentially unique (up to permutation) minimal periodic coloring for all $n$, namely the "checkerboard" 2-coloring. Here a coloring of a lattice $L$ is a coloring of the graph $G = (V,E)$ with $V = L$ and $(x,y) \in E$ if $x$ and $y$ differ by a [reduced basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction) element. (NB. I am not quite sure that this graph is the proper one to consider in general, so comments on this would also be nice.)

The root lattice $A_n$ has many minimal periodic colorings if $n+1$ is not prime (I have sketched this [here](http://blog.eqnets.com/2009/08/17/a-minimal-periodic-coloring-theorem-part-1/), and some motivation is in the last post in that series); if $n+1$ is prime, then it has essentially one $n+1$-coloring. Two minimal periodic colorings for $A_3$ are shown below (for convenience, compare the tops of the figures):

[image] 
The generic ("cyclic") coloring.

[image] 
A nontrivial example.

The lattices $D_n$ are also trivially 2-colored.

So: are there other lattices that admit more than one minimal periodic coloring? I'd be especially interested to know if $E_8$ or the Leech lattice do.

(A related question: does every minimal periodic coloring of $A_n$ arise from a group of order $n+1$?)

Answer (score 4):

When you say "reduced basis", I assume you mean that two lattice points are connected in your graph if the distance between them is the *minimum distance* of the lattice (i.e. the shortest distance between any two lattice points).

There is a simple way to generate a $24$ colouring of $E_8$ using the $8$ colouring you have for $A_8$.  It so happens that $E_8$ is isomorphic to the union of 3 translations of $A_8$,

$E_8 = A_8 + (A_8 + g) + (A_8 + 2g)$

where $g = \left( \tfrac{8}{3}, -\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)^8 \right)$.  That is, $g$ is a vector with one $\tfrac{8}{3}$ and eight $-\tfrac{1}{3}$'s. See [Martinet, Perfect Lattices in Euclidean Spaces](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=gd9CcFclBRIC&lpg=PP1&ots=Kf3Ur1gWc1&dq=martinet%252C%2520perfect%2520lattices&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false). So you just need 3 independently coloured $A_8$'s.  The resultant colouring will be periodic if the colourings for $A_8$ are periodic.  It's likely that this is not the best colouring possible for $E_8$.

Comment: Robby--Even if this isn't a minimal coloring, it is still interesting. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Dear Robby, have you looked at this one?

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22777/ 

I suggested you as someone likely to know. 

Will