# Minimal number of colours for colouring Voronoi-cells of a $d-$dimensional lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, geometry-of-numbers

There are arbitrarily large finite sets of points in $\mathbb R^3$ whose Voronoi-domains
intersect all pairwise in $2-$dimensional polytopes. This shows that one needs infinitely many
colours in order to colour "maps" of convex countries in $\mathbb R^d$ for $d\geq 3$.

The situation is however much better if the countries (in infinite number)
are the Voronoi-cells of a $d-$dimensional lattice $\Lambda$. They can always
be coloured with $2^d$ colours according to the reduction modulo $2\Lambda$
of their lattice point.

This is however not optimal as shown already by the $2-$dimensional lattices
which can always be 3-coloured (in the generic case not corresponding to 
lattices with orthogonal bases).

How far is the upper bound $2^d$ from the smallest upper bound?
(I ignore the answer even for $\mathbb R^3$.)

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11453/